# OpenGL, Culling objects that are outside the view

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport, bounding-box

In my case I wanna render 50,000 or more cubes that are distributed randomly inside a large bounding box, I don't want using instancing right now so I have to render each cube, I wanna improve the performance by culling out the cubes that are outside the camera view.
I have a camera class that has two matrices `view` and `projection`, each cube has its own bounding box, so I am planning to check each frame if the camera view bounding box contains the center of each cube if yes call its draw function if not ignore it.

I have for view matrix 3 vectors eye, target and up, and for projection width, height, near, far and FOV.

so I have two questions:

- Is this a right scenario? I will calculate the camera view boumding box each frame then test each cube.
- How can I calculate the camera bounding box each frame?

Comment: ["view frustum culling"](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/)

Comment: 50,000x12= 600,000 triangles is not too much for a normal grapics card. It will avoid fragments that are outside the fustrum. If you need to update most vertices in every frame, then the RAM->GPU transfer is slow (but not that slow). Doing culling in the CPU is really slow. Think twice if you really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an idea from here [how_to_check_if_vertex_is_visible_for_user](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/42o3xw/how_to_check_if_vertex_is_visible_for_user/) that worked fine with me.

multiplying the projection view matrix of the camera by the any point in the 3D space the visible ones should be between [-1,1].